# jQuery datepicker not working due to JavaScript version conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a web page with a JavaScript `datetimepicker` but it is not working due to another jQuery version being called to the page for another purpose. How would I make `datetimepicker` or `datepicker` work with any version of JavaScript?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
<link href="style/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="style/qweerwer.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
  var jQuery_3_1_1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
  var jQuery_1_11_1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<label class="control-label"> Event Date </label>
<div class="form-group ">
  <input style='max-width: 250px;' readonly="" name="eventdate" placeholder="Event Date" id="datepicker" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing reference to jQuery UI library, where `datepicker` function is defined. Add this line to your HTML.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: When add this library,it's working, but the calendar background is transparent.

Comment: I added this library now it is working fine. 

   

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

Answer (score 0):

Use the following js library and css:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: That library is working, the problem is when add these library it is not working boostrap tab.

Comment: <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>